# how to pass array parameters to azure arm templete deployment in terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-template-file

```
I want to send array values to arm template for terraform template deployment
```

Arm Template:-

```
"databases": {
        "type" : "array"
    }
```

I have tried using map and list in terraform but failed to do so.
Terraform Template:-

```
variable "sql_database_name" {
    type="map"
    default={
        "name"="terraformtestdb"
        "collation" = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
           "edition" = "Basic"
                  "tier" = "Basic"
                   "maxSize" = "1073741824"
                  "userName" = "admin"
                   "userPassword" = "MRK836Cu8"
                   "userRoles" = "db_datareader"
    }
}
```

Tried below syntax's

```
"databases" = "${var.sql_database_name["name"]}"--map 
"databases" = "${var.sql_database_name[0]}"--list
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: i would expect it to be a list, since map is not an array, list is

Comment: You can't use that syntax with maps - you have to use the lookup(map, key) interpolation function.

Comment: I suggest you can use the Terraform to create the individual resources, not the template, it's not an ideal way.